# Handling #N/A errors when using Excel's STOCKHISTORY function in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm using Excel's `STOCKHISTORY` function within a VBA subroutine to fetch historical stock prices for a given ticker symbol. The subroutine looks like this:

```
Public Sub GenerateStockPrices(sTicker As String, dteStart As Date, dteEnd As Date)
' ...

    On Error GoTo ErrorReceivingStockData
    mvaStockHistory = Application.WorksheetFunction.StockHistory(sTicker, dteStart, dteEnd, 0, , 0, 3, 4, 1, 2)
    mvaStockHistory = RemoveErrorsFromStockArray(mvaStockHistory)

    ' ...
    
    Exit Sub
    
ErrorReceivingStockData:
    On Error GoTo 0
    mbError = True
End Sub
```

If there's an `#N/A` error for any day within the fetched stock history, the entire `StockHistory` function call fails, and the `mvaStockHistory` array doesn't get populated at all. I want to be able to handle these errors so that I can still retrieve and process the data for the other days.

If I use the `STOCKHISTORY` function directly in an Excel cell, it returns all the stock prices except for the ones with errors. I want to be able to achieve the same in my VBA subroutine, i.e., to retrieve all the available data even if there are errors for some days.

[image: STOCKHISTORY function in Excel with #N/A error]

What modifications should I make to my subroutine to accomplish this? Is there a way to make the `StockHistory` function call succeed even if it encounters errors, or to handle the errors on a per-day basis?

Two workarounds I thought of would be to either write the formula to a cell in a hidden worksheet and then treat the data from there or use the function in VBA but loop through each day and call the function for each single day. But approaches seem however far away from best practice.

Comment: Untested, but can you try using `Application.StockHistory`, i.e. the late-bound form of `WorksheetFunction.StockHistory`?

Comment: @BigBen Thank you. I just tried that one. It still fails. But this time, mvaStockHistory contains an Error 2015 (before, I was not able to read an error from the variant).

Comment: Hmm. I wonder if you need to make multiple calls, one for each date? Or maybe use `Evaluate`.

Comment: @BigBen I just tried mvaStockHistory = Evaluate("=STOCKHISTORY(""" & sTicker & """," & CLng(dteStart) & "," & CLng(dteEnd) & ",0,,0,3,4,1,2)") but still the same issue. As I wrote in my question, looping through each day might technically work, but considering that the code should analyse a batch of probably 100 stocks over a period of several decades, I think that might make the analysis very slow. I also don't know if Microsoft limits the usage of STOCKHISTORY. But if there is no other way, then I might do it (or might do it just for the stocks with an error).

Comment: If I delete my `Option Explicit` directive, and enter a `Stop` statement immediately after the line invoking `WorksheetFunction` then, after executing `Call GenerateStockPrices("XOSL:AGLX", #January 1, 2020#, #January 1,2022#)` in the _Immediate Window_, `mvaStockHistory` is a 317 x 5 variant, only the 2nd item of which appears to contain error 2042 so, if you don't have a problem with dates then I imagine that your `RemoveErrorsFromStockArray()` procedure needs to be reviewed.

Comment: @SpectralInstance Thank you very much! I suspect I just ran into a bug with the datas ource Microsoft is using yesterday. Today, my existing method worked again with the exact same parameters (as it did some days ago). For XOSL:AGLX i still get the #N/A error for 10.05.2020 (which in itself is strange as the stock was not listed this day), but now I can again handle it. I am wondering if there was some kind of bug that did not result in an array to evaluate after all? When analyzing the Sub yesterday, I put a stop point into every line of code and can assure the the execution jumped to the row

Comment: ...mvaStockHistory = Application.WorksheetFunction.StockHistory.
I worked on a solution where the function is written to a hidden sheet and then the spill range is read into a variant yesterday. This worked fine as a workaround. But now, it seems not necessary anymore. I am not sure if I should add my code as an answer and answer my own question of if I should just accept that I ran into a bug.
Thank you BigBen and Spectral Instance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I also found the n/a problem.

Use a stock without bank holidays.

Then use stockhistory as a single line getting the start and end date from one cell.

you will then have stockhistory without holidays.

paste this in cell f1

```
=SORT(STOCKHISTORY($V$8,$V$10,$V$11,0,1,0,2,4,3,1),1,-1)
```

v8 is a stock with no bank holidays v10 and v11 are start and end dates

paste in cell a1

```
=SORT(STOCKHISTORY($V$7,f2,f2,0,1,0,2,1,4),1,-1)
```

where v7 is the stock you want to remove bank holidays from.  you'll get the header and the first row of data matching the first row in the other stock as f2 is the date.

The next cell not used is cell a3.  Paste this in a3

```
=SORT(STOCKHISTORY($V$7,f3,f3,0,0,0,2,1,4),1,-1)
```

copy and paste a3 down column a and you'll have a table of stock values without bank holidays.

Note the sort is just so the dates are descending.  You might not need it.

Another way to do this is to ignore the n/a lines and only use the lines you need using vlookup

```
VLOOKUP(F2,$A$2:$C$3000,1,FALSE)
```

I haven't noticed a difference using either method.  My macros still take a long time to run.  This happened after I went to subscription windows for the stock data.